# can you set is_safe for a global in a twig extension

Tags: twig, twig-extension

Twigs documentation for extensions show that it is possible to use "is_safe" with both simple_filters and and simple_functions, to prevent escaping of html tags in returned values, but I can see any examples of using is_safe with globals.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your global is pure HTML that needs to be rendered like HTML you could mark it as safe by using

```
$twig->addGlobal('my_html', new Twig_Markup($html, 'UTF-8'));
```

If the global is an object and returns the HTML you wrap your return value with a new `Twig_Markup`

Comment: Thanks!  Very hard to find in the twig documentation unless you know exactly what your looking for.